# Including lagged dependent variable as independent variable in linear probability model

Tags: regression, stata, lags

I am trying to replicate the Intention To Treat (ITT) analysis in one paper with two-period survey data(baseline period and followup period) and I am trying to estimate the linear probability model with the dependent variable in the followup period. However, the dependent variable in the baseline period is included in the independent variable list, I wonder if I could achieve this in Stata.

Comment: Is this a Stata question or a statistics question?

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you want to do. What I have seen is a regression where your dependent variable is the change of y between period 1 and period 2. Then you can have y in period 1 as a control variable.

For example, let's say you have variables `period` (for the time period, pre- and post) and `unit` (for the treated unit). `treat` is the treatment status and `y` is the outcome. Then:

```
bys unit (period): gen depvar = y[2]-y[1]
bys unit (period): gen y_pre = y[1]
keep if period == 2
keep unit treat depvar y_pre
reg depvar i.y_pre##i.treat
```

Is that what you are looking for?